# function use prev state not current state

Tags: reactjs

when change date  i need to fire function doFilter  which uses the current change of date
but it is using prevState not new state

```js
onChangeDate = (dates)=>{
    let [start, end] = dates;
    const selectedDateFrom=Moment(start).format("YYYY-M-D");
    const selectedDateTo=end?Moment(end).format("YYYY-M-D"):end;
    this.setState({start,end})
    this.setState({selectedDateFrom,selectedDateTo})
    this.doFilter()
}
doFilter=()=>{
    axios.get(`API?keyword=${this.state.keyword}&status=${this.state.selectedStatus}&dep_id=${this.state.selectedDep}&sumission_date_from=${this.state.selectedDateFrom}&sumission_date_to=${this.state.selectedDateTo}&rate=${this.state.selectedRate}`, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': *******
            'Authorization':*******
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        const historyList= response.data.order;
       this.setState({historyList,loading:false})
    },(error)=>{
        if(error.response){
            this.setState({cerrmsg : error.response.data.message,loading:false,show:true,historyList:null
            })  
        }
        else{
          this.setState({cerrmsg : null})
        }
      })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of these two lines:

```
this.setState({selectedDateFrom,selectedDateTo})
this.doFilter()
```

Your `doFilter` will not wait until `setState` gets executed

Solution is to use setState-callback ... to make sure `doFilter` gets executed after successfully updating state:

```
this.setState({selectedDateFrom,selectedDateTo}, () => {
    this.doFilter()
})
```

**Plus**

I guess there's need to call two subsequent `setState` ... cause each one will force re-render

I mean convert:

```
this.setState({start,end})
this.setState({selectedDateFrom,selectedDateTo})
```

Into

```
this.setState({start, end, selectedDateFrom,selectedDateTo})
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState({selectedDateFrom,selectedDateTo})` setState function is asynchronous and does not guarantee updated state in next line.

One solution would be a callback function of setState and the second option would be checking prevState with nextState.

Please see the snippet below.

componentDidUpdate will be called on every state update.

```js
onChangeDate = (dates)=>{
    let [start, end] = dates;
    const selectedDateFrom=Moment(start).format("YYYY-M-D");
    const selectedDateTo=end?Moment(end).format("YYYY-M-D"):end;
    this.setState({start,end})
    this.setState({selectedDateFrom,selectedDateTo})
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 if(prevState.selectedDateFrom !== this.state.selectedDateFrom) {
  this.doFilter()
 }
}
```

```js
this.setState({selectedDateFrom,selectedDateTo}, this.doFilter())
```